# iOS 13: Dark Mode not confirmed?

Tags: ios, display, settings, dark-mode

Am I correct that Dark Mode in iOS 13 has **not** been publicly confirmed?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking about future products, unreleased products or Apple plans is off topic here. See [What’s off and on-topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: Thanks & my apologies. I’m a effectively a noob again, & 100% on SE. If I am able to edit, I’m happy to remove reference to specific feature, leaving it a question solely about Apple policy, rather than plans.

Comment: bmike—Please ignore my previous. Apologies again: I read full on/off-topic & even my revised “policy” question is not appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: It’s OK - no need to delete it, just hang tight until you have a practical problem to solve and then we’ll be super happy to host questions about released software. Beta is a little tricky so read up on [meta] for how to proceed while software is in beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No details of upcoming major OS releases will be confirmed until [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/).

If you are interested in details about upcoming iOS releases, be sure to watch the WWDC 2019 keynote or read the coverage at websites such as [9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com) or [MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com) on the week of June 3.

Comment: Thanks! I haven’t kept an eye out in a long time & never for iOS or devices. A couple of mention seemed phrased as if official, which surprised me.